# Flutter AspNet Core SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 192.168.1.87, port = 46186)

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to connect using my smartphone (not emulator) to my Aspnet Core with SignalR backend.
I added Cors to Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.AddSignalR();
    }

readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "AllowOrigins";
...

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

I tried to connect with an Angular frontend and it works well, and I would like to do the same with my Flutter App.
Here's part of the code:

```
const url = 'http://192.168.1.87:44327/signalrtc';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("$url").build();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    hubConnection.onclose((_) {
    print("Connessione persa");
    });

    hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", onReceiveMessage);
    startConnection();
  }

  void startConnection() async {
    print('start');
    await hubConnection.start();
  }
```

I'm only using [Flutter SignalR package](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_client) and I copied my local computer IPv4 to connect to my backend, because as I already said I'm not using an emulator so I can't insert 10.0.2.2, but if I try to run the App it will gives me that error.
Both my computer and my smartphone are connected to the same network.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't believe that this is a CORS issue. Let's see if anyone can answer this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I just installed [Conveyor by Keyoti](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti) for Visual Studio.

[ASP.NET Core - remote access from smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549389/asp-net-core-remote-access-from-smartphone)

> With it you don't have to change any configuration, it just runs in the background and gives you a port you can use remotely, and also it can tunnel to the internet so you have a public URL if you like.

You only need to install it, run in debug mode and opening Keyoti you'll find another URL that you can use for your smartphone.

[image]

In the end I changed my URL in the Flutter project from:

```
const url = 'http://192.168.1.87:44327/signalrtc';
```

To:

```
const url = 'https://192.168.1.87:45456/signalrtc';
```

Basically is my IPv4 given from keyote but with another port.